# Add a self-made python module to my heroku app

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I'm trying to launch a Python-Heroku application. One of my app requirement is a self-made module saved into a *.tar.gz. I'm loading properly the module in my local environment, but when I load it into Heroku it doesn't find it.

```
git add .
git push heroku master

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/dash-alphav6.git'
```

Do you have any idea of how to upload my self-made module to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Try hosting your module on GitHub and then adding the git repo and executing pip install
This method is described by Heroku's own support: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#git-backed-distributions
For public repos:

```
git+git://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git
```

For private repos:

```
git+https://user:password@github.com/nsa/secret.git
```